# How to chat with multiple pdfs (that have different information) using langchain?

Tags: python, next.js, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

Currently I have managed to make a web interface to chat with a single PDF document using langchain as a framework, OpenAI as an LLM and Pinecone as a vector store. However, when I wanted to introduce new documents (5 new documents) PDF to the vecotres store, I realized that the information is different from the first document.

I have thought about introducing the resulting embeddings of all the pdf documents to Pinecone. But I have a doubt about whether the information can be crossed when specific information is requested from only one PDF document.

So I'm thinking that another way could be to add some selectors in the same web interface so that the user can choose from the PDF they want to obtain answers from. and thus the information is directed to the specific PDF. But perhaps the user's interaction with the web interface would not be so automatic.

This is why I want to find a way to send all pdf documents to pinecone, and perhaps in the vector store itself add an index for each document or add more collections. I appreciate if anyone has worked on something similar and can give me advice to continue with my task.

Comment: From your question above it is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to implement a [RAG](https://research.ibm.com/blog/retrieval-augmented-generation-RAG) pattern. Do you want to answer questions based on multiple PDFs/documents?

Comment: Hello @DanielSchneider, I think the second. I mean if I had 5 pdf documents (A, B, C, D, E of different content) for example. And I send the embeddings to the vector store. When I ask in the web interface about a topic related to the pdf document "D" I want the information obtained in the response to be only from the document "D". And there is no interference with the content of the other documents. Since Langchain allows you to return 5 chunks of content compared to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to ensure that when you query for information related to a specific PDF document (e.g., "D", as you mentioned on your comment), the response should only include information from that particular document without interference from the content of other documents (A, B, C, E), you should store and query the embeddings for each document separately.

Combining all documents into one loses the granularity of individual documents. This means you won't be able to retrieve or analyze information at the document level. Any query or analysis will be based on the entire combined content. That means the dimensionality of the combined vector can be quite high. High-dimensional data can be challenging to work with in terms of computational resources and storage.

It is also difficult to update the combined documents. For example, if document A gets updated, then you need to combine all the documents again and then restore them. This will be a very expensive operation.

The benefit of combining all the documents is you can run a complex query.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification @Yilmaz , I can now understand the situation better.

Comment: @Yilmaz Some more questions about file structure perhaps: I wonder how smart it really is. Does it actually also take the file name in account? And when a document is split into chapters, will it take the name of the chapter in account when parsing the content of that chapter? In a text file a chapter is often just a line of text followed by an empty line, so I imagine this to be challenging. And what about PDF loaders, will it take the formatting in account to get a sense of structure of the document? - Sorry, those are a lot of questions.